# Upgrading mysql release from 5.1.41 to 5.1.5

Tags: mysql, upgrade

How do I upgrade the release for mysql server?

I want to upgrade from 5.1.41 to 5.1.5

Do I have to do an entire reinstall?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, from 5.1.41 to 5.1.5 is a massive downgrade. Current version is 5.1.50 (the numbers are integer counters, not decimal fractions).

Beside that, the single most important thing is a working backup. After that, there is the question how you did install it in the first place?

- If you used your distributions package, you should try to find an updated binary package for that distribution.
- If you installed form source, you must compile it with the same path parameters and install it (while mysql is stopped, of course).
- The same is true for Windows binary installers.

Either way, your data files should continue to work, but you must run mysql_upgrade to allow for possible modifications of the binary format to take place before restarting the daemons.